Website doesn't have a robot.txt, but Lighthouse says 'robots.txt is not valid' and shows index.html as robot.txt
I didn't add robot.txt to an Angular app (we don't need it) and documentation says that it's not necessary to add it.
But when I run a Lighthouse SEO check it says 'robots.txt is not valid 62 errors found' and shows content of index.html as robot.txt.
Looks like it generates robot.txt from index.html, how to stop it from doing it?
I can't reproduce it locally, only when deployed to environments
